# Ironpython 2.7.3 Visual Studio Missing Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ironpython

I have installed IronPython 2.7.3. I would see a IronPython project in the visual studio.
I have visual studio 2010 professional. My problem is that. I do not see the Iron Project.
Why, where is that? Now I am downloading the Ultimate. Maybe the version of the visual studio is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The project templates are part of [PTVS](http://pytools.codeplex.com), not IronPython. Old versions of IronPython did include Visual Studio templates, but they were removed in favour of PTVS.